# Is there a way I can find what HOMEBREW_CC/XX was set to when I installed a package

Tags: homebrew

Some of what I'm doing is very compiler dependent. Is it possible to check if, for example, the `boost` formula was installed with the gcc-4.9 or clang compiler?

What I'm looking for might look like this:

```
$ echo HOMEBREW_CC

$ brew install boost
$ <comand>
    built with clang
$ brew uninstall --force boost
$ export HOMEBREW_CC = gcc-4.9 ;  export HOMEBREW_CXX = g++-4.9
$ brew install boost
$ <command>
    built with gcc-4.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is listed in the receipt

```
$ cat /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json 
{"used_options":["--c++11","--with-mpi","--without-single"],"unused_options":["--universal","--with-icu4c","--without-static"],"built_as_bottle":false,"poured_from_bottle":false,"time":1437512231,"HEAD":"1d7b6215cbe7d690e961f1a72f497a58c95f6de4","stdlib":"libstdcxx","compiler":"gcc-5","source":{"path":"/usr/local/Library/Formula/boost.rb","tap":"Homebrew/homebrew"}}~
```

..Although I hacked together another solution

```
diff --git a/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb b/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb
index bf11af0..1c1caf3 100644
--- a/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb
+++ b/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb
@@ -774,7 +774,9 @@ class Formula
           "version" => keg.version.to_s,
           "used_options" => tab.used_options.as_flags,
           "built_as_bottle" => tab.built_bottle,
-          "poured_from_bottle" => tab.poured_from_bottle
+          "poured_from_bottle" => tab.poured_from_bottle,
+          "cc_compiler" => tab.cc_compiler,
+          "cxx_compiler" => tab.cxx_compiler
         }
       end

diff --git a/Library/Homebrew/tab.rb b/Library/Homebrew/tab.rb
index 37b0db2..de0fe11 100644
--- a/Library/Homebrew/tab.rb
+++ b/Library/Homebrew/tab.rb
@@ -182,6 +182,16 @@ class Tab < OpenStruct
   end

   def to_json
+  if ENV['HOMEBREW_CC'] then
+    cc_compiler = ENV['HOMEBREW_CC']
+  else
+    cc_compiler = "clang"
+  end
+  if ENV['HOMEBREW_CXX'] then
+    cxx_compiler = ENV['HOMEBREW_CXX']
+  else
+    cxx_compiler = "clang" 
+  end
     attributes = {
       "used_options" => used_options.as_flags,
       "unused_options" => unused_options.as_flags,
@@ -192,6 +202,8 @@ class Tab < OpenStruct
       "stdlib" => (stdlib.to_s if stdlib),
       "compiler" => (compiler.to_s if compiler),
       "source" => source,
+      "cc_compiler" => cc_compiler,
+      "cxx_compiler" => cxx_compiler  
     }

     Utils::JSON.dump(attributes)
```